# Integration of TokenCredential with AzureServiceTokenProvider

Tags: .net, azure

This question is for Azure.Core 1.1.0.0 and newer.

As of this version `TokenCredential` is an abstract class so the old constructor cannot be used anymore. I would like to use the result of `AzureServiceTokenProvider` (which internally calls az cli) to get access tokens to be used for other Azure services (in my case download blobs). I have written a simple class derived from TokenCredential which takes the resulting token and returns an `AccessToken` instance but I can't believe this would be missing in the SDK, although I cannot find it.

I have looked through all the derived classes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet) in the documentation, but none of them provides what I want, i.e. completely automatic obtaining of the token (assuming the user is already logged in in the az cli or some other precondition is satisfied).

This is the class I have written. Is there something similar that would achieve this?

```
    public class AzureServiceTokenCredentials : TokenCredential
    {
        private readonly AccessToken _token;

        public AzureServiceTokenCredentials(AppAuthenticationResult result)
        {
            _token = new AccessToken(result.AccessToken, result.ExpiresOn);
        }

        public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => _token;

        public override ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
            new ValueTask<AccessToken>(Task.FromResult(_token));
    }
```

Comment: DefaultAzureCredential does what you want IMO.

Comment: @juunas did not work for me. EnvironmentCredential - something different, ManagedIdentityCredential - is for MSI for VMs in cloud, not users, SharedTokenCacheCredential - I have not really found much about this, but it did not use the tokens from az cli or it wasn't present and it didn't obtain new one, InteractiveBrowserCredential - interactive, not what I wanted